# Unity NavMesh on a Sphere Unity 5.6 Navigation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navigation, navmesh

with Unity 5.6 the NavMesh / Navigation has changed in some parts. My Question is:

Is it now possible to create a NavMesh, that covers a whole sphere ?

Thank you for your Answers!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would theorical work, but there is no feature (yet, maybe) that would do that for you. You'd have to make for every mesh a seperate navmash and then link them together accordingly to their position.
If you did make a spherical navmesh, you could make a video or gif about it.

Comment: If you have problems with the rotation of your player, you can use the normals of the triangles of the mesh

Answer (score 0):

Here is my spherical navmesh on complex topology: [youtube](https://youtu.be/IQAkS9bbkwo)
In short - I baked my planet 6 times, rotating different sides up. Then I manually added baked navmesh pieces, setting it`s rotation. And then connected it with off mesh links (sure, it must be more accurate for production).